# Official Snap store app problem

Tags: 18.04, updates, snap, canonical

I just installed official [snap store app](https://snapcraft.io/install/snap-store/ubuntu) from Canonical. (Until now I managed snaps via terminal.) When I selected the "Installed" tab and click on an item which has updates, it shows the "Update" button for a few seconds and then the Update button disappears. Can someone explain the reason and how to fix it.I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with latest updates installed. (except snap updates)

** Sometime ago I had a [problem with snapd service using so much data](https://askubuntu.com/q/1131621/360794). So please note that I have followed that instructions on that [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1131682/360794). (if that causes this problem)

[image]

Comment: Doesn't snap automatically apply updates?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Sometime ago I had a problem about that. So I fixed it with this https://askubuntu.com/q/1131621/360794

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks for reminding me. I updated the question.