# usr/lib/snapd/snapd uses much bandwidth

Tags: internet, 19.04, bandwidth, nethogs

My problem is with `snapd`. When I connect my pc to my mobile hotspot, my pc downloads lots of data. I downloaded `nethogs` and I saw `usr/lib/snapd/snapd` downloads sometimes with mb/s.
I thought this could be resolved with an update, but the "Software Updater" application doesn't help.
I tried to disable "automatically check for updates" in 'Software & Updates' but that doesn't help either.
I found `sudo systemctl stop snapd.service` command and after running it, `/usr/lib/snapd/snapd` is missing from `nethogs` (not downloading anything) but after ~1-2 min, it starts downloading again.

How can I stop that download?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem in Ubuntu 20. Stopping snap service got the job done.
Read this instructions, it worked for me.
[How to stop snapd from auto-updating?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045542/how-to-stop-snapd-from-auto-updating)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I tried everything even " **systemctl mask** ".. It worked but the solution was temporary when you unmask the program, it starts consuming bandwidth again. Solution was simple, just uninstall snapd and reinstall. This really bothered me as I don't have a fixed internet connection.

TLDR; Uninstall then reinstall snapd with apt command.