# How do I configure update settings that I would do from the GUI in the terminal?

Tags: apt, bash, updates, gnome-terminal

I need to configure update settings from the terminal that I would regularly do with the GUI. This includes settings which things are downloadable, which updates to install, how often it checks for updates, automatically installing updates, and notifying me about new versions. I know it’s probably something that I should have figured out on my own, but I can’t find anything.

Comment: If you are talking about disabling automatic updates, [your answer is here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1190969/167115). If you want to change how often the system checks for updates, it appears this is done daily but the timing is somewhat random to prevent everyone from hitting the servers at the same time.  As for adding or removing a repository, see [this answer for how to remove a repository or ppa](https://askubuntu.com/a/345473/167115) and do the opposite (run the command without the `-r` flag) to add a repository or ppa.

Comment: Thanks a heap @mchid

Comment: So to add the universe repository, for example, you would run `sudo add-apt-repository universe` to remove this repository, you would run `sudo add-apt-repository -r universe`. For a ppa, you would use the ppa name with `ppa:` as described in the answer.

Comment: This works great @mchid