# Investigate why ubuntu servet 18.04 keeps shutting down

Tags: 18.04, server, shutdown

I found this [very useful answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278166/131568) at first I thought it was because of unattended upgrades,
then followed recommendations [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1190969/169110), but the system still shuts down.

Below are partial outputs of the mentioned commands, I don't know what else to do before actually changing hardware.

Thank you very much everyone!

This is the output of: last -x | head | tac

```
runlevel (to lvl 5)   4.15.0-128-gener Tue Jan  5 22:52 - 22:59  (00:06)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-128-gener Tue Jan  5 22:57   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   4.15.0-128-gener Tue Jan  5 22:59 - 00:50  (01:51)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-128-gener Wed Jan  6 00:49   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   4.15.0-128-gener Wed Jan  6 00:50   still running
user1   pts/1        192.168.1.20     Wed Jan  6 03:44   still logged in
user1   pts/0        :pts/1:S.0       Wed Jan  6 03:59 - 03:59  (00:00)
user1   pts/0        :pts/1:S.0       Wed Jan  6 03:59 - 04:09  (00:09)
user1   pts/0        :pts/1:S.0       Wed Jan  6 04:10 - 04:11  (00:00)
user1   pts/0        :pts/1:S.0       Wed Jan  6 04:43 - 05:14  (00:31)
```

And this is part of the output of

```
 grep -iv ': starting\|kernel: .*: Power Button\|watching system buttons\|Stopped Cleaning Up\|Started Crash recovery kernel'   /var/log/messages /var/log/syslog /var/log/apcupsd*   | grep -iw 'recover[a-z]*\|power[a-z]*\|shut[a-z ]*down\|rsyslogd\|ups'

grep: /var/log/messages: No such file or directory

/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.049508] ACPI: Power Resource [USBC] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.053135] ACPI: Power Resource [PLPE] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.053994] ACPI: Power Resource [PLPE] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.068250] ACPI: Power Resource [CLK0] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.068356] ACPI: Power Resource [CLK1] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.235790] pci 0000:01:00.1: D0 power state depends on 0000:01:00.0
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 apparmor[596]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 dbus-daemon[900]: dbus[900]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 kernel: [    4.852026] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 kernel: [    5.518198] EXT4-fs (sdb2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 kernel: [    5.518208] EXT4-fs (sdb2): write access will be enabled during recovery
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 kernel: [   17.492117] EXT4-fs (sdb2): recovery complete
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 rsyslogd: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (fd 3) from systemd.  [v8.32.0]
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 106
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 102
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:56 medesvr1 rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.32.0" x-pid="935" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:07:57 medesvr1 systemd[1]: Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:08:36 medesvr1 set-cpufreq[897]: Setting powersave scheduler for all CPUs
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 18:08:41 medesvr1 systemd[1]: Started LXD - container startup/shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 apparmor[599]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.049486] ACPI: Power Resource [USBC] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.053108] ACPI: Power Resource [PLPE] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.053967] ACPI: Power Resource [PLPE] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.068215] ACPI: Power Resource [CLK0] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.068321] ACPI: Power Resource [CLK1] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.235872] pci 0000:01:00.1: D0 power state depends on 0000:01:00.0
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 kernel: [    4.920040] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 kernel: [    5.576970] EXT4-fs (sdb2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 kernel: [    5.576980] EXT4-fs (sdb2): write access will be enabled during recovery
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 kernel: [   44.073736] EXT4-fs (sdb2): recovery complete
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 dbus-daemon[905]: dbus[905]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 systemd[1]: Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 set-cpufreq[985]: Setting powersave scheduler for all CPUs
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 rsyslogd: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (fd 3) from systemd.  [v8.32.0]
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 106
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 102
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:16 medesvr1 rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.32.0" x-pid="890" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:52:29 medesvr1 systemd[1]: Started LXD - container startup/shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 apparmor[600]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 dbus-daemon[918]: dbus[918]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 systemd[1]: Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 rsyslogd: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (fd 3) from systemd.  [v8.32.0]
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 106
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 102
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.32.0" x-pid="967" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.049489] ACPI: Power Resource [USBC] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.053111] ACPI: Power Resource [PLPE] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.053967] ACPI: Power Resource [PLPE] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.068203] ACPI: Power Resource [CLK0] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.068309] ACPI: Power Resource [CLK1] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.235732] pci 0000:01:00.1: D0 power state depends on 0000:01:00.0
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 kernel: [    4.540036] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 kernel: [    5.203817] EXT4-fs (sdb2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 kernel: [    5.203826] EXT4-fs (sdb2): write access will be enabled during recovery
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:22 medesvr1 kernel: [   36.208830] EXT4-fs (sdb2): recovery complete
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:58:57 medesvr1 set-cpufreq[965]: Setting powersave scheduler for all CPUs
/var/log/syslog:Jan  5 22:59:03 medesvr1 systemd[1]: Started LXD - container startup/shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 apparmor[593]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 dbus-daemon[891]: dbus[891]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 systemd[1]: Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.049501] ACPI: Power Resource [USBC] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.053123] ACPI: Power Resource [PLPE] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.053983] ACPI: Power Resource [PLPE] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.068240] ACPI: Power Resource [CLK0] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.068346] ACPI: Power Resource [CLK1] (on)
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 kernel: [    0.235940] pci 0000:01:00.1: D0 power state depends on 0000:01:00.0
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 kernel: [    4.560044] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 kernel: [    5.188958] EXT4-fs (sdb2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 kernel: [    5.188969] EXT4-fs (sdb2): write access will be enabled during recovery
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 kernel: [   32.240760] EXT4-fs (sdb2): recovery complete
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 rsyslogd: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (fd 3) from systemd.  [v8.32.0]
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 106
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 102
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:49:58 medesvr1 rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.32.0" x-pid="928" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
grep: /var/log/apcupsd*: No such file or directory
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:50:05 medesvr1 set-cpufreq[885]: Setting powersave scheduler for all CPUs
/var/log/syslog:Jan  6 00:50:28 medesvr1 systemd[1]: Started LXD - container startup/shutdown.
```

Comment: The settings for Unattended Upgrades are in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`, including reboot-if-needed (DO NOT REBOOT is the default setting). There seems no need to disable UU, which provides a valuable service to your system. One imagines you would remember (or, better yet, record) if you had changed the UU settings.

Comment: Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false"; was commented and set on true, I enabled it and set it to false