# kubuntu 18.04: constantly writing on disk

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, ssd

I'm using kubuntu 18.04. When I do:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1
```

I see the SSD is super hot since this morning (70+ Celsius) --I can feel the laptop unusually hot right of the mouse pad-- and in the "Data Units Written:" row, hundreds of GB got written since this morning (I check every few hours since this morning) when all I did is using slack video conf. Is this normal? The ssd capacity usage is still the same at 30%. Is this some background task? How to find which one?

----Even when I don't do anything with the laptop there is 2.5MB/sec being written to disk (according to iotop's "Actual disk write", written by "snapd"). And again, total disk is still only 30% filled (so these writes don't fill the disk).

Comment: See if you can install `iotop` and it should show what is writing to your disk so much.

Comment: a command called "snapd"

Comment: Possible:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1839237

Comment: @Terrance: yes, looks like it. Do you know how to fix?

Comment: One person in the bug said that they disabled and re-enabled the snap service.  Try stuff from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045542/how-to-stop-snapd-from-auto-updating  The second answer there shows how to disable.