# Disabling snapd with systemctl

Tags: 20.10

snapd is enabled by default in Ubuntu as doing a `systemctl status snapd` quickly reveals which is of course expected. So I tried the following:

```bsh
$ sudo systemctl disable --now snapd
$ sudo systemctl disable --now snapd.socket
```

The first command warns that `snapd.socket` could reactivate `snapd` (hence my second command) and the second outputs that a symlink has been removed (as expected when disabling most services/sockets with `systemctl`). I then did a reboot to confirm that the changes persisted. To my surprise, `systemctl status snapd` outputs the following (trimmed for convenience):

```
● snapd.service - Snap Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-10-31 13:09:38 HKT; 14min ago
TriggeredBy: ● snapd.socket
```

And `systemctl status snapd.socket` outputs the following:

```
● snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-10-31 13:09:38 HKT; 15min ago
   Triggers: ● snapd.service
```

The outputs above indicate that both the service and the socket have been disabled as expected; however, both statuses are still `active (running)`. Why might that be? Is there perhaps some startup script in Ubuntu that ensures that `snapd` remains running despite being "disabled"?

In case it matters, this was done on Ubuntu 20.10 (in a freshly created VM for testing), though I've first noticed similar behavior on my bare-metal Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation on one of my older machines.

P.S. I'm actually not *too* bothered by `snapd` running in the background and am not aiming to remove it but would just like to know why Ubuntu exhibits this behavior (and whether disabling it for real without removing it entirely is feasible).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop snapd from auto-updating?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045542/how-to-stop-snapd-from-auto-updating) . Or in short use `mask` instead of `disable`.

Comment: Thanks, that does answer my immediate question. But following the links prompted me to look into it a bit deeper and I would like to answer my own question with my additional findings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @N0rbert suggested in a comment, *masking* the service instead of just disabling it should do the trick.

However, digging into it a bit deeper, I was lead to [a post on systemd in Fedora Magazine](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-masking-units/) published back in late 2015, which states that:

> Recall that systemd can understand dependencies between units. This means systemd can tell when one unit must be started to allow another to run.
>
> Furthermore, systemd uses this information to start a required service, **even if disabled**, to satisfy dependencies.

So following this hint, I listed the reverse dependencies of `snapd.service` and `snapd.socket` by doing `systemctl list-dependencies --reverse snapd` (and similarly for `snapd.socket`), to see which units depended on `snapd`. It turns out that `snapd.seeded.service` (which was enabled) depended on `snapd.socket`. Once I executed

```bsh
$ sudo systemctl disable --now snapd.seeded
```

and rebooted, all three units were `inactive (dead)` as expected.