# Ubuntu 20.04 shows laptop's brand name for too long on boot

Tags: boot, 20.04

When I boot my ubuntu 20.04 on a Samsung laptop, the brand name shows up for 40 seconds. Then the ubuntu purple screen appears then it instantly loads further.
Is there any way to configure some settings so as to not to wait to see my laptop's brand name for 40 seconds?
My grub looks something like this.

[image: Grub]

[image: systemd-analyze blame|head output]

Also, running dmesg, I observed [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usp4g.png)

[sda3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A66gn.png) happens to be my root partition..
Is it weird that it is taking too much time?

Comment: Nope. it takes as long as it takes, hardware issue.

Comment: won't having SSD be making a difference.. I have my OS on SSD and the rest on HDD

Comment: Can you please open a terminal and type `systemd-analyze blame | head` then post the result (edit your question above and add the new text).

Comment: @darth_epoxy done..

Comment: All the answers and comments you are getting are after the machine logo is gone and deal with the OS start up not your question.

Comment: Also, I had made some changes regarding Network Manager as by default, Ubuntu didn't auto-connect to hidden wifi on system boot or reboot..

Comment: @David actually my hardware shouldn't really be falling behind.. So, I thought there might be other issues causing the problem..

Comment: If you are not using snaps, you can disable snapd.service with `sudo systemctl mask snapd.service` See https://askubuntu.com/a/1059602/124466

Comment: @biplab-dutta since this is about laptop manufacturer logo, which would appear BEFORE grub or Ubuntu logo, have you checked settings in `BIOS` / `UEFI`? Settings like waiting for network boot or wait time before booting. Thanks.

Comment: If you F2 when you start up and go into the bios setup, can you see anything related to safe boot or secure boot?

Comment: This is a hardware problem. The OS only kicks in after GRUB and GRUB kicks in after the logo.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses.. I have no idea what happened but now the brand logo only appears for 10 seconds.. I have no idea why it stopped misbehaving.. But if it ends well, that's what matters..

Answer (score -1):

If you are tired of staring at the logo while it boots, you can press <kbd>esc</kbd> or <kbd>tab</kbd> whie it boots and watch the boot messages.  If you like this better, you can make it permanent by removing `quiet splash` from the grub command line in `/etc/default/grub` and run `update-grub`.  (Some people think the logo is pretty.  I'd prefer to know what is going on.)

If is the slow boot that annoys you rather than actually staring at the logo, you can use `systemd-analyze` to mesure what is taking so long in the boot and optimize it.

For clarification, newer versions of Ubuntu show both the manufacturer's logo and graphics for Ubuntu during the boot process.  So it is unclear if what you are seeing is part of the laptop's POST or if it is Ubuntu booting while leaving the manufacturer's logo on the screen.

In both cases, pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> may leave the logo screen to show details of what is going on.  If it is the laptop's POST that is taking your 40 seconds, then there's nothing Ubuntu can do about that and it's actually off topic for this forum.

Your output from `systemd-analyze blame` says at least 9 seconds of that 40 could be ubuntu booting.

Comment: The laptop's brand name appears for 40 seconds not the Ubuntu logo.. the Ubuntu logo after appearing proceeds immediately to the login screen.. so, I have no problem with the logo thing.. My main concern is how to avoid watching my laptop's brand name (not Ubuntu logo) for 40 seconds on boot

Comment: Updated answer for clarification.  Have you tried hitting tab in those 40 seconds?

Comment: Yeah most of us totally misunderstood the question, sorry. Your BIOS when first powered up runs a hardware self test, then the UEFI BIOS has to initialise. The only thing I have noticed that is proven to increas BIOS loading time is peripherals i.e. usb connections and extra monitors. You can test this by cold booting as is, noting the time is still 40s, then shutting it down and remove EVERYTHING then power on again and time it. Let us all know please.