# snapd consumes all available CPU and hangs my VPS

Tags: server, webserver, wordpress

I have a new development instance on DigitalOcean. It is a LAMP with Wordpress without any content yet. Nevertheless the Wordpress backend frequently hangs and times out. I installed htop to help me identify which processe are consuming the resources and that is how I noticed snapd.

snapd consumes all available CPU capacity which in turn causes mysql connection to drop and both front end and back end time out/error out.

Why is snapd doing this and what can I do to make it stop?

EDIT: If you do not know do not suggest answers. Assume that I have in fact searched. Yes, I know I can stop it from automatically updating, nevertheless why would a simple snapd update hang my system? I want to fix this issue, not bury it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop snapd from auto-updating?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045542/how-to-stop-snapd-from-auto-updating)