# LXD : /var/snap/lxd/.../unix.socket: connect: no such file or directory

Tags: server, lxd

I have Ubuntu 18.04 running with LXD in the host and about 300 containers. 
LXD (as the title suggests), was installed using `snap`.

In the past year, I have faced twice this error (last time was yesterday): `/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket: connect: no such file or directory`.
The error happens when using `lxc` command (any command).

The problem is that even though the containers are operating as usual, I can not control them anymore.

I have read about a similar bug report here: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/5423. Restarting the service throws no error (and seems to be successful), but the error persists. Even starting it in `debug` mode, show no errors or malfunction.

The best solution so far has been to restart the server but that means offline time for all containers.

I suspect the reason is due to snap refreshing automatically, but it seems that [disabling it is not an alternative](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930593/how-to-disable-autorefresh-in-snap). Reverting didn't change anything.

What do I need to do to prevent such kind of situations? or in the worst case, how can I recover from such state without restarting?

Unfortunately the server was restarted so I can not test it now, but I would like to know for future reference.

Comment: I faced the same error again in other setup and the reason was that `lxd` was installed using `snapd` and the `lxd-client` was previously installed using apt.

Answer (score 0):

Every LXC Operation or process is captured in a socket file.

You are not having this **/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket** file. By Some-means, it might got deleted.

This is the reason why you are not able to do any lxc operations.

**Just try creating that file with no contents**.

```
sudo vi /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket
```

No Restart of LXC Service needed.

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks. While that is generally true, in my case that file existed. I think LXD fails to use that socket. If that happens again, I will be sure to use your recommendation if that file is not there.