# What may be the reason for unnecessary internet data consumption by Ubuntu 18.04 OS even automatic update is stopped?

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet

In my laptop I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS OS as a dual boot OS alongside of Microsoft Windows 10 OS. I stopped the automatic update process. Normally I connecting my laptop with mobile tethering based Wi-Fi hotspot. Recently my laptop consumes more than 1 GB of internet data within few minutes when connecting it without doing any internet access process by manually with frequently. So I tried USB tethering also and I faced same problem. What may be the reasonable causes for my problem and how to resolve it. Guide me to resolve my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you have many snap apps installed? You can check by running `snap list`. [This many be useful](https://askubuntu.com/q/930593/480481).

Comment: You can find out which processes have internet connections open with `sudo lsof -i`

Comment: Is it your browser consuming bandwidth? What happens with reboot and no chrome or Firefox?

Comment: @pomsky: As per your suggested link Now I ran the command [sudo snap set system refresh.metered=hold]  Thank for your response.

Comment: @waltinator as per your suggestion  the sudo lsof -i command gives all are 0 sizes.. I couldn't understand from that.. Thanks for your response..

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: The data consumed when connect to the wi-fi without opening any browser or any other human activity.

Comment: I installed pycharm. Is it update automatically? if possible suggest me which are all the common softwares updates automatically. Anyhow I stopped automatic update in software & updates

Comment: "Anyhow I stopped automatic update in software & updates" that does NOT stop snap updates. neither does `sudo snap set system refresh.metered=hold` snaps WILL update at some point in time. Did you check the online accounts? Those should be "off" by default. Also apport/whoopsie can go to the outside (though not 1Gb :) ) see https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport

Comment: @ Rinzwind :  As per your link.. Some answer was to stop/mask the apport service. But, one answer was "do not stop apport, it will create problem if any crash happens".  What may be is my right choice?