# Every once a while my Chromium snap will fail to load any page. A reboot always fixes it. What could be the issue

Tags: 20.04, snap, chromium

Every once a while my Chromium snap will fail to load any page. Closing and reopening Chromium doesn't resolve the problem.  A reboot (of the OS) always fixes it. What could be the issue?[image]  I'm guessing it's something snap related but that's just a guess.  Any idea how I could resolve such an issue without rebooting? I'm running stock Ubuntu 20.04 w/ Gnome.

The error messages presented is the typical 'Aw, Snap!" Error. Error code SIGTRAP

Comment: [How to disable autorefresh in snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930593/how-to-disable-autorefresh-in-snap) `sudo snap set core experimental.refresh-app-awareness=true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely [the result of a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1914918) that happens when the Snap package is updated while Chromium is running. Closing and re-opening the Chromium snap does not always resolve the issue because there may be background processes owned by the application that are still running. Rebooting the machine will flush these processes out of memory.

If you would like to avoid the occasional mid-day reboot, you might find that the Edge or Firefox browsers are a bit better about updates despite their many other quirks

Comment: note that if you disable the following setting : Continue running background apps when Chromium is closed. you won't need to reboot. closing and reopening chromium will be enough. still annoying though

Answer (score 0):

Close Chromium.

Then run:

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'chromium' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Open chromium again.