# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes for exactly 10 seconds during boot, then works normally

Tags: boot, freeze

I have a notebook LG Gram 14z980 with Windows 10 by default.
I installed Ubuntu 20.04 with dual boot and I notice that the boot time in Windows were much faster than Ubuntu (about 10 seconds).
Then, I investigated dmesg and guess what... Ubuntu freezes exactly 10 seconds doing "nothing", then continues booting normally.

Example of dmesg:

```
[    2.561970] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: FPC 
[   12.934435] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C52B.0002/input/input6
```

I recently upgraded it with an additional SSD NVme (Crucial P5) and 16 GB RAM (Kingston Fury) and the behavior keeps the same, even with a fresh Ubuntu installation.

[image]

Does anyone have an advice on how to fix this?
w
I tried the following commands and I realized that the NetworkManager-wait-online.service  was taking 6.237 seconds during boot. Then I disabled it, but dmesg keeps showing 10 seconds freezing as I posted.

Some new details of the current status:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
3.119s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                               
2.093s snap-spotify-56.mount                                                    
2.092s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1519.mount                                  
2.068s snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-261.mount                                      
1.890s snap-snapd-12704.mount                                                   
1.762s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1515.mount                                  
1.754s snap-snapd-14066.mount                                                   
1.645s snap-snap\x2dstore-547.mount                                             
1.463s dev-loop0.device                                                         
1.452s snap-snap\x2dstore-558.mount     
...

$ systemd-analyze critical-chain

graphical.target @6.535s
└─multi-user.target @6.535s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @4.605s +731ms
    └─snapd.service @3.296s +1.307s
      └─basic.target @3.261s
        └─sockets.target @3.261s
          └─snapd.socket @3.260s +847us
            └─sysinit.target @3.255s
              └─systemd-timesyncd.service @2.531s +163ms
                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @2.505s +21ms
                  └─local-fs.target @2.498s
                    └─snap-spotify-56.mount @394ms +2.093s
                      └─dev-loop16.device @2.483s +6ms
```

None of them seems to take 10 seconds.

Comment: Look at all the startup logs: `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Find the timestamps that are 10 seconds apart. Also `sudo systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @waltinator 
I tried the commands you sent but they were not sufficient to solve the problem. The command blame helped to identify that the `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` was taking 6.237s during boot. Then, I disabled it, but dmesg keeps showing 10 sec freezing as I posted. I checked the command `sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain`, which confirmed `NetworkManager-wait-online.service @4.311s +6.237s`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend disabling [snapd at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930593/how-to-disable-autorefresh-in-snap) and [Waiting for Network to come up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do/1018731#1018731).

There are [other steps to speed up boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156317/how-to-speed-up-boot-time-on-lubuntu/1161515#1161515).

All three of these links provide a wealth of information. The links are all in Ask Ubuntu so they will not disappear until this answer does.