# In snap: "error: unknown flag hold"

Tags: updates, 22.04, snap

Snap automatic updates can now be disabled with `$ sudo snap refresh --hold`.

This can be seen in [this other thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930593/how-to-disable-autorefresh-in-snap) and [this blog post](https://merlijn.sebrechts.be/blog/2022-11-10-turn-off-snap-updates/) and [from the mouth of the horse](https://snapcraft.io/blog/hold-your-horses-i-mean-snaps-new-feature-lets-you-stop-snap-updates-for-as-long-as-you-need) itself.

My Ubuntu 22.04 is up to date but I get an error when running the command. **Any idea why?**

```
$ sudo apt update
...
All packages are up to date.

$ sudo snap refresh
All snaps up to date.

$ sudo snap refresh --hold
error: unknown flag `hold'
```

Comment: There is no `--hold` option in `snap` AFAIK. Did you look at the man documentation?

Comment: @FedKad: I did look at the man pages and there's no `--hold` option. But if you look at the linked thread there are answers there suggesting it's use.

Comment: ... your "mouth of the horse" link describes it as *"The new hold feature"* so perhaps it is not available in your version? According to the [roadmap](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapd-roadmap) it was added in 2.58, whereas Ubuntu 22.04 has 2.56.2

Comment: @steeldriver: Ah, you're right! It's 2.58 in roadmap and I have 2.57.6 (`$ snap --version`). Strange that others are mentioning the use of `--hold` in relation to Ubuntu. Maybe they're using Ubuntu 22.10 or another distro but still dropping comments on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @steeldriver: I'll accept your comment as an answer since it explains why `--hold` isn't working in 22.04.

Comment: @Daniel I added an answer for the record

Comment: `snap --version` at Ubuntu 22.10 is `snap    2.57.6
snapd   2.57.6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the third link in your question:

> ### Refresh hold
>
> The new hold feature allows system administrators and end users to
> stop or postpone their snap updates for as long as necessary.

Searching around a bit, [The snapd roadmap](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapd-roadmap) indicates that the `refresh --hold` feature was added in version 2.58. Meanwhile, Ubuntu 22.04 currently provides 2.56 at the latest:

```
$ apt policy snapd
snapd:
  Installed: 2.56.2+22.04ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.56.2+22.04ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.56.2+22.04ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.55.3+22.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

So, your version simply doesn't support the feature.

---

In Ubuntu 22.10:

```
$ apt policy snapd
snapd:
  Installed: 2.57.5+22.10ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 2.57.5+22.10ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.57.5+22.10ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.57.4+22.10ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 Packages
```

So, even Ubuntu 22.10 does not have this option.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo snap refresh snapd --edge
```

or if you don't have snapd installed as a snap:

```
sudo snap install snapd --edge
```

And after that --hold and --unhold flags will be at your service!